# Roboblender annotation processing not working

Tags: android, roboguice

I try to make Roboblender work with Roboguice but the compile time processing doesn't seem to do anything, the AnnotationDatabaseImpl class is not generated. (Project builds without error.)

I even created a sample project, please see below. What do I miss?
(I know the gradle task and the second metadata would only be needed for multi module project, but it didn't work without them either).

build.gradle:

```
project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { task ->
    options.compilerArgs << "-AguiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName=gk.com.roboguice_compile"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
}
```

manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="roboguice.modules"
        android:value="gk.com.roboguice_compile.RoboguiceBindings" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="roboguice.annotations.packages"
        android:value="gk.com.roboguice_compile" />
```

activity:

```
@ContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @Inject
    private PresentMaker presentMaker;
```

bindings:

```
public class RoboguiceBindings extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(PresentMaker.class).to(BirthdayPresentMaker.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AnnotationDatabaseImpl was there but only under the build directory not among the source files.

My bad, probably every annotation processor work like this.
(Although strangely [this project](https://github.com/Liffft/SimpleAndroidArchitecture) has the AnnotationDatabaseImpl generated in the project root..).